# Order get_terms by multiple values

Tags: terms

Orderby of get_terms() does not accept array type. How do I make this code works?

```
$allcities = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'city',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'count' => 'ASC' ), 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
        'key' => 'country',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        )
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Get terms in any order and sort the result using usort(), for example.

Answer (score 1):

`WP_Term_Query`, which powers `get_terms()`, does not support ordering by multiple properties the same way `WP_Query` does.

But, since you don't need to  worry about pagination, you'll be able to achieve the result you want by sorting the results after querying them:

```
$allcities = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'city',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

usort( $allcities, function( $a, $b ) {
    $a_country = (int) get_term_meta( $a->term_id, 'country', true );
    $b_country = (int) get_term_meta( $b->term_id, 'country', true );

    return $a_country - $b_country ?: $a->count - $count;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacob's method works, but I found a better way (I think) by using only one sql request.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.*, tr.meta_value as country
        FROM $wpdb->terms AS t 
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->termmeta
        ON ( t.term_id = $wpdb->termmeta.term_id )
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt
        ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->termmeta AS tr
        ON t.term_id = tr.term_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('city')
        AND tr.meta_key = 'country'
        ORDER BY cast(country AS unsigned) ASC, tt.count DESC;
```